# How To Use List Custom Settings In Process Builder Criteria

Tags: process-builder, list, customsetting

I have List custom settings which I'm using within APEX to determine criteria I should use when building functionality.  I have some workflows also however I know I can't use List Custom Settings within the workflows therefore I was looking if there was a way I can do field updates via config otherwise (based on criteria to determine whether the updates should occur).  I've had a look at Process Builder. I'm pretty inexperienced with Process Builder so not too familiar with it.  I note when I add a criteria the filter fields available are from the Object I define for the Process Build.  I was wondering can I mix and match criteria, to have some criteria using fields from my Custom Object & also criteria from List Custom Settings? If List custom settings can be used how are they used when adding criteria?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you can only use Hierarchy Custom Settings in Workflow, Visualforce, Process Builder, and other places. They are accessed through the $Setup [Global Variable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5). This is one of those places where you'll continue to need to use Apex Code, or you'll need to configure the Process Builder to use a Flow to query those values, though this process is still pretty laborious. In the future, you'll be able to reference [Custom Metadata](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata.htm), but it's my understanding that this is still a pilot. There are no plans to ever support List Custom Settings in places where we currently use formulas (though, of course, they're free to change their mind on this).

Comment: CMDT in Validation Rules are about to be GA in Summer '18. [PM's recent Forward Looking Statements](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E32UQAS) are that they'll come to Formulas & Default Values in Winter '19 and PB "after".

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Yeah, I knew it wasn't available now, but that it was a thing that would happen. I just didn't know the time frame; thanks for the link.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks. This is what I thought, that List Custom Settings could not be used in Process Builder also, then I read it somewhere on forums that it could be (but I guess this is wrong).  Thanks for clarifying. I'll have a look into how Flows can be used in conjunction with this. It would be nice to keep it more dynamic and avoid further Apex code also.  I'll see how I get on but If I can't get the flow option to work I might just abandon trying to use config.