# Custom Settings - Unable to access or see custom setting in Flows

Tags: list, customsetting, visual-flows

I created a Custom Setting with `Visibility - Public & Type - List` to reference in Flows. But I don't know why I can't find the value. I noticed other Custom Settings with `Type - Hierarchy` are available but not the one I just created.

Custom Setting name: Flows__c
Field: Value__c

To reference in flow I tried to access with this: `{$Setup.Flows__c.Value__c}`

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Use List Custom Settings In Process Builder Criteria](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218503/how-to-use-list-custom-settings-in-process-builder-criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer via this StackExchange post: [How To Use List Custom Settings In Process Builder Criteria](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218503/how-to-use-list-custom-settings-in-process-builder-criteria)

=> We can't access Custom Setting with Type - List in Flows at the moment.